# PHP: Unable to pass variable from class a to b

Tags: php, oop

I have researched and tried different methods but I am just unable to pass the variable from main class to children class. Doing `var_dump` always displays NULL. Is this because of I am sending as an array?

Userdata.class.php

```
    <?php

/**
 *  Class used for getting userdata
 */
class Userdata
{
  public $userdata;

  function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function getUserData($username, $password)
  {
    $this->userdata = array
      (
        'arr_username' => $username,
        'arr_password' => $password
      );
    return $this->userdata;
  }
}
```

Authenticate.class.php

```
require_once('Userdata.class.php');
/**
 * This class is used for user authentication/validation/form
 */
class Authentication extends Userdata
{
  var $userdata;

  function logIn()
  {
    var_dump($this->userdata);
  }

}
```

session_handler.php

```
function formSubmitUser()
{
  // Class the class Authentication
  $userdata = new Userdata();
  $userdata->authentication = new Authentication;
  //First submit the form before processing the data
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $userdata->getUserData($username, $password);
    $userdata->authentication->logIn();
  }
}
```

Everything seems to work if I manually add values to main class __construct. But if I try to get it from function `getUserData` I can't get it to work.

```
  function __construct()
  {
    $this->userdata = "Sending data like this works";
  }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you just not understand how work OOP.

Comment: That is why I am trying to learn it instead just asking everything all the time. Help me get to right direction with it? I always search for all of my issues but I can't seem to find a solution to my issue.

Comment: Don't use var, use public or private

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For your code should work next

```
function formSubmitUser()
{
  // Class the class Authentication
  $userdata = new Authentication;
  //First submit the form before processing the data
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $userdata->getUserData($username, $password);
    $userdata->logIn();
  }
}
```

Comment: Such a simple thing, yet that was the case. Thank you so much for that. I swear I remember at some level people have used the first method I had .
$userdata->authentication->logIn();

Answer (score -1):

in class Authentication you are not calling the parent variable from your Userdata class
thats the reason why you get NULL from your var_dump. in Authentication $userdata has no value.
try var_dump(parent::$userdata);
this should give you access to it

Answer (score -1):

First, it's not common to make a getter method as a setter I suggest if the user data is an array you should instantiate it in the constructor.

```
  function __construct()
  {
      $this->userdata = array();

  }
  public function setUserData($username, $password) {
      $this->userdata['username'] = $username;
      $this->userdata['password'] = $password;
  }
  public function getUserData() {
      return $this->userdata;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You're redeclaring the userdata variable in Authentication which essentially is overriding the one coming from the Userdata class. Remove `var $userdata` from Authentication class

Answer (score -1):

you should follow the inheritance rules. You do not need to create instances of both classes.
Use it instead of your session_handler.php

```
function formSubmitUser()
{
  $authenticator = new Authentication;
  //First submit the form before processing the data
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $authenticator->getUserData($username, $password);
    $authenticator->logIn();
  }
}
```

Let me know, if you need any other help

Comment: Thanks for the tip. If you don't mind how do I set $authenticator->getUserData($username, $password);
 $authenticator->logIn(); into
$authenticate->setUserData($username, $password)->logIn(); ?

Comment: Add following method in your "Userdata.class.php".

public function setUserData($username, $password)
  {
    $this->userdata = array
      (
        'arr_username' => $username,
        'arr_password' => $password
      );
    return $this;
  }